# ORA 12514 error:TNS listener error

Tags: oracle11g, tns

Ok everything worked fine till yesterday now i am suddenly getting this error 
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
nothing had been modified

```
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = jainam-2b1c493d)(PORT = 1521))
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVER = DEDICATED)
  (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
)
)

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

  ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
      (DESCRIPTION = 
     (ADDRESS_LIST = 
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
     (CONNECT_DATA = 
   (SID = CLRExtProc) 
   (PRESENTATION = RO) 
 ) 
)
```

I am totally stuck and have no idea what to do.
I tried help from here 
http://dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12514_tns_listener_does_not_currently_know_service_requested.htm
 but no use.
Thanks

EDIT:

here's the output to `lsnrctl service`

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 3 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
      "ORACLE SERVER" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:25 state:ready
        CLRExtProc
     (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\NTN_6B4_641B624E_B22.ORA))
  "ORACLE SERVER" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:25 state:ready
     CLRExtProc
     (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\NTN_6B4_641B624E_282.ORA))
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Handler(s):
  "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
     LOCAL SERVER
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
 Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
 Handler(s):
  "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
     DISPATCHER <machine: JAINAM-2B1C493D, pid: 3708>
     (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=jainam-2b1c493d)(PORT=2763))
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Handler(s):
  "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
     LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on this error, but fought with a bit. Are you sure that the machien running oracle can still reach the host?

Comment: Could you try a `tnsping [yourconnection]` on the command line and see what it says?

Comment: @Deruijter yes tnsping 127.0.0.1 is able to connect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons you get that kind of error is because database instance started before listener did. Listener must always be started first.

1. Check if a database instance is up and running
2. Check the output of the `lsnrctl service` command and see what services are registered.
3. Check if you have `SERVICE_NAME` correctly specified when connecting to the instance.
4. If it happens that database instance stared before listener did, sometimes you just need to wait a little or you can execute `alter system register` in order to register the instance.

Comment: @user1461078 check what? What do you mean?

Comment: No. Still cant make the connection.

Comment: did you check off all items? try to connect like this                 1) sqlplus /nolog                                                   2) SQL> connect  /  as sysdba.

Comment: Thanks man, after doing this and hen restarting the service it worked.BUt still dont know where the problem was...

Comment: For me the error occurred, because my oracle cloud autonomous database was stopped after 7 days: _There are no recent active connections to your database. Inactive Always Free Autonomous Databases are automatically stopped after 7 days._ I had to restart the database in the web interface https://cloud.oracle.com/db/adb
So step 1. was the cause.

Answer (score 5):

For me it helped to add the following SID_DESC into the C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN\listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    ...
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
    )
  )
```

After restarting listener and database the access worked again.

Thanks to http://grow-n-shine.blogspot.de/2011/11/oracle-11g-xe-issue-ora-12514.html

Comment: when everything else failed, this should do the trick for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me too in a quite restrictive environment, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Open SQL Plus and connect to System User:

```
system/p@ssword
```

And run two commands:

```
SQL> alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))' scope=both;
SQL> alter system register;
```